# Is there scriptural support for Madhwa's "atat tvam asi"?

Tags: madhwa, interpretation

The book

"A History of the Dvaita School of Vedānta and Its Literature", Volume 1
By B. N. Krishnamurti Sharma

says in the footnote of page 373 that

Madhwa, in his Chandogya Bhashya cites a  post-upanishadic interpretive source called "Sama Samhita" to support his Sandhi split to derive "atat tvam asi".

Is this scripture still available and can this claim be verified?